# align ul in div

Tags: html, css, layout

Can somebody help me to align my ul in the div, so that it will be aligned at the bottom of the div.

```
<div id="metanav_top">
    <ul class="metanav">
      <li>Entry 1</li>
      <li>Entry 2</li>
      <li>Entry 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

Please have a look to my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4zBT/).

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You don't mention what browsers you need to support, but if you don't need older browser support, you can use `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: bottom` on the div. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4zBT/3/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should [learn about the `position` property](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/) in CSS. You won't get far without it.

```css
#metanav_top {
    position: relative;
}

ul.metanav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y4zBT/6/)